# Assigning properties to a javascript object using dynamic property names

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I would like to do something like this but I have no idea, and I can't use js() to insert any dynamic data into because js() only takes constant string parameters (or is there a way to do that?)

```
    val doc: dynamic = Any()
    doc._id = name
    data.forEach {
        it.forEach { entry ->
            // need to set property of the doc using entry.key as the property name with entry.value
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can using [indexed access](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/dynamic-type.html) just like as javascript bracket access notation, for example:

```
val doc: dynamic = Any()
doc._id = name
data.forEach {
    it.forEach { entry ->
      // v--- kotlin process the brackets []= as a set operator
      doc[entry.key] = entry.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ycomp Not at all.

Comment: Note the object has to be of `dynamic` type